# Make rsync print unicode filenames correctly

Tags: rsync, macintosh

I'm using rsync on Mac, during file syncing, unicode filenames are not correctly displayed, e.g

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: What version of `rsync` on each end of the transfer? (`rsync --version`)

Comment: @roaima `rsync  version 2.6.9  protocol version 29`, the one shipped with sierra

Comment: @roaima It's just a local folder sync

Comment: See [Rsync with special character files not working between Mac and Linux](https://askubuntu.com/questions/533690/rsync-with-special-character-files-not-working-between-mac-and-linux). I understand your situation is Mac only but it might be worth a read.

Comment: @roaima Problem resolved, I've installed another verison of rsync via homebrew, it works with or without that iconv option ... sigh

Answer (score 5):

The default rsync shipped with MacOS Sierra does not seem to recognize unicode.

To resolve the problem, install another verison of `rsync` via `homebrew`

e.g `brew install rsync`

Comment: Or through Nix: `nix-env -iA nixpkgs.rsync`